# Limiting the quantity inside of a Bundle product

Tags: bundled-product, quantity, select

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:

Customer can select from 3 types of bundle: 12 donuts, 24 donuts, 36 donuts

I have 50 different type of donuts to select from.

How to I make sure the client selecting the buddle of 12 donuts can, first not go over 12 donuts and second adjust the quantity for the type of donuts he wants.

Has anyone ever succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see how to achieve this without custom product types is using bundle products with 12/24/36 options, where each option has a fixed qty of 1 and all 50 donuts as possible selections.

This means, the shop frontend will show 12/24/36 dropdowns and the customer has to select each single item.

If you want a different frontend, like qty inputs for each donut with validation, I would still suggest this approach. You can hide the original dropdowns, create the interface as you like it and use JavaScript to set the correct values in the hidden dropdowns.